# Procedure never inserts some rows - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, insert, deadlock

I have stored procedure who inserts row by row in four tables, based on some conditions. It doesn't work very well, because in some cases it doesn't insert row in one of the tables (I suppose it comes to DEADLOCK or whatever similar). Here is the procedure, but insert statements are omitted for clearer view of SP (if it is necessary, I'll post it full).

In ELSE part of second IF statement procedure needs to insert SINGLE row, but it doesn't. **All other parts are correct and inserted**, but from whole transaction **only** `AvlDataSegmentStartPosition` table stays without row inserted.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Uspinsertintoavldata] (@DeviceId     BIGINT, 
                                              @AvlTimestamp DATETIME, 
                                              @Priority     TINYINT, 
                                              @Lon          REAL, 
                                              @Lat          REAL, 
                                              @Altitude     SMALLINT, 
                                              @Angle        SMALLINT, 
                                              @Satellites   TINYINT, 
                                              @Speed        SMALLINT, 
                                              @AvlDataId    BIGINT out) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      BEGIN TRAN 

      DECLARE @oldAvlDataId BIGINT; 
      DECLARE @currentTime DATETIME = Getdate(); 

      INSERT INTO dbo.[avldata] ...

      SET @AvlDataId = @@identity 

      UPDATE dbo.[lastavldata] WITH (serializable) 
      SET    ...
      WHERE  [deviceid] = @DeviceId 
             AND [avltimestamp] < @AvlTimestamp 

      IF @@rowcount = 0 
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                         FROM   dbo.[lastavldata] 
                         WHERE  [deviceid] = @DeviceId) 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO dbo.[lastavldata] ...
        END 

      UPDATE dbo.[lastavldatasegmentstartposition] WITH (serializable) 
      SET    ...
      WHERE  [deviceid] = @DeviceId 
             AND [avltimestamp] < @AvlTimestamp 
             AND ( ( [speed] < 5 AND @Speed >= 5 ) 
                    OR ( [speed] >= 5 AND @Speed < 5 ) ) 
      -- this is the IF statement where error occurs
      IF @@rowcount = 0
        -- when data comes here it is all right
        BEGIN 
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                           FROM   dbo.[lastavldatasegmentstartposition] 
                           WHERE  [deviceid] = @DeviceId) 
              BEGIN 
                  INSERT INTO dbo.[lastavldatasegmentstartposition] ...
              END 
            ELSE 
              SELECT @oldAvlDataId = a.avldataid 
              FROM   dbo.[avldatasegmentstartposition] a 
              WHERE  a.[avltimestamp] = 
                     (SELECT Min([avltimestamp]) 
                      FROM   dbo.[avldatasegmentstartposition] 
                      WHERE  [deviceid] = @DeviceId 
                             AND [avltimestamp] > @AvlTimestamp 
                     ) 
                     AND ( ( [speed] < 5 AND @Speed < 5 ) 
                            OR ( [speed] >= 5 AND @Speed >= 5 ) ) 

            IF @oldAvlDataId IS NOT NULL 
              BEGIN 
                  UPDATE dbo.[avldatasegmentstartposition] 
                  SET    ...
                  FROM   dbo.[avldatasegmentstartposition] 
                  WHERE  [avldataid] = @oldAvlDataId 
              END 
        END 
      ELSE
        -- WHEN DATA COMES HERE, ROW OFTEN IS NOT INSERTED IN FOLLOWING TABLE
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO dbo.[avldatasegmentstartposition] 
                    ([avldataid], 
                     [deviceid], 
                     [avltimestamp], 
                     [priority], 
                     [lon], 
                     [lat], 
                     [altitude], 
                     [angle], 
                     [satellites], 
                     [speed]) 
        VALUES      ( @AvlDataId, 
                      @DeviceId, 
                      @AvlTimestamp, 
                      @Priority, 
                      @Lon, 
                      @Lat, 
                      @Altitude, 
                      @Angle, 
                      @Satellites, 
                      @Speed) 
        END 

      COMMIT TRAN 
  END
```

If somebody needs more explanation, just ask.

Comment: You cut too much. Is there a `select` or list of constants? `Deadlock` is a real **exception** by the way, so you would notice if it occurs.

Comment: @IvanStarostin There is SP input parameters that are passed to SP and used inside it.

Comment: Last insert that does not work - what is the source for it?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Edited. AvlDataId is identity from other table (first inserted), and all other parameters are input ones.

Comment: I see, thanks. Did you ensure that you fall into that block ever? In the case  when this insert must be performed - did you check that you reach this insert statement? Place a simple `print "test"` in there and run.

Comment: Aleksander, with complex issues like this it helps to send us sample tables. You can debug sprocs these days, so try that. The other thing you can do is use the Sql Server Profiler. Use the SP:StmtCompleted, SP:StmtStarting, SQL:StmtCompleted, SQL:StmyStarting events. These will show which statements are actually being executed in your sproc and you should see the issue in the logic. As others have said a deadlock is a very serious error in your logic and will be seen as an exception, because SQL Server terminates the process.

Comment: This procedure is called by application. We collect live data from cars and insert into these tables. Because it is "very live" procedure (called at least once per second), I'm not able to play with it very easy.

Comment: You can use xp_logevent instead of PRINT